# Binding NSArrayController to NSSearchField and viewing result in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nssearchfield

My app description,

1. Add `NSMutableArray` with some items (say 1- 50)
2. Add `NSArrayController` and add/bind that array to this arrayController
3. Add `NSTableView` to my view and populate them using the concept of **BINDINGS**.
4. Finally add a `NSSearchField` and complete the app by adding/binding the NSArrayController with searchField.

I would like to know if this approach is how it is meant to be, I have searched but couldn't find a way of displaying populated arrays in a `NSTableView` using `NSArrayController` binds.

Help me through.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Bind your `NSSearchField` to the same `NSArrayController` you use for the `NSTableView`
2. In bindings for your `NSSearchField` under **Search** and **Predicate** set the **Controller Key** to `filterPredicate` and **Display Name** to `predicate`
3. Under **Predicate Format** write something like: `self.name contains[cd] $value`

Comment: Michael, I tried a Predicate Format like `self.name contains[cd] $value OR self.title contains[cd] $value` but it doesn't work. Do you know how to combine to predicate?

Comment: Auto-answer: put parenthesis. `(self.name contains[cd] $value) OR (self.title contains[cd] $value)` works.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to combine several predicates, follow Mikael steps and do:

- Under **Predicate Format** write something like: `(self.name contains[cd] $value) OR (self.title contains[cd] $value)`